# Directed distances between a set of N points in 2D

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing

I have N points in the plane stored as a (N, 2) shaped numpy array and I need to calculate the forces between them: F_ij = V(|r_i - r_j|)(r_i - r_j), where V is 
a function that only depends in the distance between the point i and j. In code-language, I need to run multiple times the following more efficiently:

```
import numpy as np
def V(dist):  #Here, dist is a float
    return np.exp(-dist)/dist


N = 10000
r = np.random.rand((N, 2))
F = np.zeros((N,N,2))

for i in range(N):
    for j in range(N):
        r_rel = r[i, :] - r[j, :]  #Relative position
        dist_rel = np.sqrt(r_rel[:, 0]**2 + r_rel[:, 1]**2)
        F[i, j, :] = V(dist_rel)*r_rel
```

This maybe can be performed more efficiently by using some memory-store trick (this 3-tensor is memory expensive), by doing only half of the double-for operations (because F[i,j,:]=-F[i,j,:]), etc. So, I ask for how to do this.

The function cdist of scipy module is very similar to this and run like x12 times faster than the above code, so, in one hand, maybe there is a function that do what I want in scipy/numpy and, in other hand, the above code can be written more efficiently.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Your approach has a computational complexity of Ω(n²), which is going to be slow for large n.  It's certainly possible to get rid of the explicit for loop in favour of vectorised operations, which will speed this up by a constant factor, but it will still be Ω(n²).  A proper solution would be to sort your points into a quadtree and use a hierarchical multipole expansion on the branches, which would allow you to achieve a complexity of Ω(n log n), which for large n will beat any Ω(n²) algorithm.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yeah, I know, but with this question I only want to low the constant in O(n^2). I the time reduces to half I will be happy hahah. Anyway, do you have reference of the "hierarchical multipole expansion on the branches"? It is the Barnes-Hut simulation that said paisanco, right?

Comment: your `V()` function approaches zero pretty quickly.  If you put a lower limit on your precision you can easily reduce your computation time by only calculating force for distances smaller than a set threshhold.  Then you could also use a `kdtree` instead of `cdist` (or `pdist` which would probably be more applicable here).  I assume the next step is `np.sum(F, axis = 2)`?

Comment: @VeridianDynamics What I meant seems indeed be called "Barnes-Hut simulation".  I didn't know the approach had a fancy name when applied to the n-body problem specifically, since it's pretty much a standard appraoch used for all kinds of simulations, inlcuding in electromagnetics, quantum physics, gravitational microlensing for globular clusters and everything else that deals with a large number of spacially distributed objects influencing a potential.  I guess the excellent answers you got so far cover how to speed this up by a constant factor.

Comment: @VeridianDynamics If it isn't necessary to write the code in Pure Python, wrapping up a non Brute-Force method to Python eg. https://github.com/JAChapmanII/barnes-hut/tree/master/src should also be considered.

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches come to my mind.

First, is to use the scipy [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html). But it has a couple of issues. Since, it expects the output of the custom distance function to be a scalar, so we need to calculate the x and y coordinates of the force separately. Second, it will do the calculations for all the pairs i,j and j,i again. So, as mentioned in the question we can reduce the calculation to n^2/2. On N = 1000, it takes 14.141 sec. For N = 10000, takes forever. Calculations made on 8 GB, 8 core mac.

```
import time
import numpy as np 
from scipy.spatial import distance

N = 1000
r = np.random.rand(N, 2)

def force(a, b):
    def V(dist):  #Here, dist is a float
        return np.exp(-dist)/(dist+1)

    r_rel = a - b  #Relative position
    dist_rel = np.sqrt(r_rel[0]**2 + r_rel[1]**2)
    return V(dist_rel)*r_rel

def force_x(a, b):
    return force(a,b)[0]
def force_y(a, b):
    return force(a, b)[1]

t1 = time.time()
# Calculate x and y coordinates separately
F_x = distance.cdist(r, r, metric=force_x)
F_y = distance.cdist(r, r, metric=force_y)
print("Time taken is = ", time.time() - t1) # takes 14.141s
```

Second, method which takes care of the n^2/2 optimization is to use the n^2 loop but to speed up the calculations using numba. If you have a gpu, you can further speed up by `numba vectorize`. **On N = 1000, it takes 0.240 sec. For N = 10000, takes ~25 sec**.

```
import numba as nb
@nb.jit(nb.float64[:,:,:](nb.float64[:,:]), nopython=True, cache=True)
def distance(r):
    N = r.shape[0]
    F = np.zeros((N,N,2))
    for i in range(N):
        for j in range(i):
            r_rel = r[i] - r[j]  #Relative position
            dist_rel = np.sqrt(r_rel[0] ** 2 + r_rel[1] ** 2)
            V = np.exp(-dist_rel) / (dist_rel+1)    
            F[i,j] = V * r_rel
            F[j,i] = -1 * F[i,j]
    return F

t1 = time.time()
F = distance(r)
print("Time taken is = ", time.time() - t1) # takes 0.240s
```

So, apart from making the O(n logn) method described in the link in the comments, the numba method seems to work for the example size in the question under acceptable time.

Answer (score 2):

This should be a comment to @Deepak Sainis answer. 
Apart from his already good answer there are some performance critical problems.

**1. Declaration of arrays**

```
nb.float64[:,:,:](nb.float64[:,:])
```

This means that both the input and output array can be non-contigous in memory. This often prevents SIMD-vectorization. If your arrays are definitly contigous you can declare

```
nb.float64[:,:,::1](nb.float64[:,::1])
```

which means the arrys are C-contigous.

Or you can simple drop the declaration, Numba will detect the datatype and the contigousness itself correctly.

**2. Using many small loops which can be unrolled**

Every additional loop comes with some overhead. In this example it is known that the second dim of the array r will be 2. You can unroll the "hidden loops" manually. This improves the performance more than an order of magnitude in this example.

```
#eg. this
r_rel = r[i] - r[j]
#can be rewritten to
r_rel_1 = r[i,0] - r[j,0]
r_rel_2 = r[i,1] - r[j,1]
```

**3. Calculating the results only once and copying sounds like a good idea**

```
F[j,i] = -1 * F[i,j]
```

This line prevents SIMD-vectorization and has a very high cost (read/write to arrays contigously) if you can. This simple operation takes almost a bit longer than calculating all the values directly. But if you know that there is some kind of symetry you can avoid this copying process completely.

**4. Using np.zeros if you overwrite the results anyway**

This has about (1/3) of the cost of calculating the upper half of the array. In the backend there is always a np.empty() to allocate memory. If you use np.zeros, there is a nested loop which writes zeros to the whole array which is very costly.

**5. Parallelization**

On small problems this can have negative impact on performance, but larger problems benefit from it. Caching isn't available for parallelized functions and the compilation time is higher.

**Single threaded version**

```
@nb.jit(fastmath=True,error_model='numpy',cache=True)
def distance(r):
    N = r.shape[0]
    F = np.empty((N,N,2))
    #give the compile all information available
    assert r.shape[1]==2
    for i in range(N):
        #change i to N to get all results
        for j in range(i):
            r_rel_1 = r[i,0] - r[j,0]
            r_rel_2 = r[i,1] - r[j,1]
            dist_rel = np.sqrt(r_rel_1 ** 2 + r_rel_2 ** 2)
            V = np.exp(-dist_rel) / (dist_rel+1)    
            F[i,j,0] = V * r_rel_1
            F[i,j,1] = V * r_rel_2
    return F
```

**Parallel version**

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True,error_model='numpy',fastmath=True)
def distance(r):
    N = r.shape[0]
    F = np.empty((N,N,2))
    #give the compile all information available
    assert r.shape[1]==2
    for i in nb.prange(N):
        #change i to N to get all results
        for j in range(i):
            r_rel_1 = r[i,0] - r[j,0]
            r_rel_2 = r[i,1] - r[j,1]
            dist_rel = np.sqrt(r_rel_1 ** 2 + r_rel_2 ** 2)
            V = np.exp(-dist_rel) / (dist_rel+1)
            F[i,j,0] = V * r_rel_1
            F[i,j,1] = V * r_rel_2
    return F
```

**Timings**

Core i7 Quadcoe 4th gen, Python 3.5, Numba 0.4dev
There is always the second call to the function measured, to avoid measuring compilation overhead. There is only one half of the array calculated. I commented the line `F[j,i] = -1 * F[i,j]` for a direct comparison.

```
N=1000    
@Deepak Saini: 109ms
single_threaded: 6.4ms
parallel:5ms

N=10000
@Deepak Saini: 10.43s
single_threaded: 0.61s
parallel:0.36s
```

Comment: Woah!! Really thanks for taking time to write this insightful answer. Seems like small things do make a big difference.

Comment: Can you elaborate on point 3 further, maybe provide some link which explains SIMD in detail on modern processors. Thanks.

Comment: @Deepak Saini: Something like that https://llvm.org/docs/Vectorizers.html#scatter-gather (Numba is based on  LLVM) or https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/putting-your-data-and-code-in-order-optimization-and-memory-part-1 ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to do the time-expensive `np.exp` and `np.sqrt` functions on distances that will cause `np.exp(-dist)` to underflow to zero. The smallest double greater than zero is `5e-324`, and `-np.log(5e-324) = 744.44007192138122`. Now in your exampe the minimum distance is only ~1.4, but I assume that in practice the distances will be larger.  With that in mind we can do:

```
import numpy as np

def V(dist_sq, thr = 5e-324):  #Here, dist_sq is dist**2, a float
    d_sq_thr = np.log(thr)**2  
    mask = dist_sq < d_sq_thr  # mask is True where you want to do calculations
    out = np.sqrt(dist_sq[mask]) # square root only in place and only for valid distances
    out = np.exp(-out) / out  # same with `np.exp`
    return out, mask

i, j = np.triu_indices(N, 1)  # gives you the valid (i, j) values
r_rel = r[i] - r[j]
sq_distances = np.sum(r_rel**2, axis = 1)  # squared distances
v_, mask = V(sq_distances)
F[i[mask], j[mask], :] = v_ * r_rel[mask]
F[j[mask], i[mask], :] = -F[i[mask], j[mask], :]
```

Now, you can set your `thr` value to something larger than machine precision and speed things up even more, even before you start jumping into wrapping it in`numba` as @max9111 suggests. Not a `numba` expert, but I think this would work:

```
@nb.njit(parallel=True,error_model='numpy',fastmath=True)
def distance(r, thr = None):
    if thr == None:
        d_sq_thr = np.log(5e-324)**2
    else:
        d_sq_thr = np.log(thr)**2 
    N = r.shape[0]
    F = np.zeros((N,N,2))
    #give the compile all information available
    assert r.shape[1]==2
    for i in nb.prange(N):
        #change i to N to get all results
        for j in range(i):
            r_rel_1 = r[i,0] - r[j,0]
            r_rel_2 = r[i,1] - r[j,1]
            dist_rel_sq = r_rel_1 ** 2 + r_rel_2 ** 2
            if dist_rel_sq > d_sq_thr :
                continue
            dist_rel = np.sqrt(dist_rel_sq)
            V = np.exp(-dist_rel) / (dist_rel+1)
            F[i,j,0] = V * r_rel_1
            F[i,j,1] = V * r_rel_2
    return F
```

Keep in mind this method *will* be slower than the others on your toy problem, as the distance check is just overhead (as your `r` values are all bounded on [0,1]), but when larger distances are used this should speed things up - maybe even a lot.

Comment: The potential speedup by this is limited to about 30-50%. The problem will quite soon be memory limited. The costly functions (np.exp and np.sqrt) are the only reason why this problem isn't a pure memory bandwith benchmark. But if there are any summations like you suggested in the comments and they are directly done in the Numba function, the threshold method can lead to quite a bit more speedup. Nevertheless you are right, a kd-tree aproach should be the way to go and outperform all other methods.

Comment: @max9111 thanks, not an expert on the computational nuts and bolts at the memory bandwidth level.  Is there a reason you changed the OP's `V()` function to include `(dist_rel +1)` instead of just `dist_rel`?  I maintained it becasue I wasn't sure what would happen if I didn't.

Comment: No, I only tried to make some performance improvements to Deepak Sainis approach. I have to check this.  But all in all the question has to be updated. eg. wrapping up this https://github.com/JAChapmanII/barnes-hut/tree/master/src may be a much better aproach anyway.